# How binary data type is really stored?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field for SHA256 passwords as binary(32). If I use a select statement I will see something like`0x81B637D8FCD2C6DA6359E6963113A1170DE795E4B725B84D1E0B4CFD9EC58CE9`. I want to know how they are really stored?

I have a function (written in C#) which basically hash a password (return byte and not string) and when I compare it to the database, It works fine without the need of making the hash to Upper or add the 0x prefix like in SQL. As weird as this may sound, I don't understand why the comparison works? because If I ever try to convert that byte result to string in C#, I will get something like `81-B6-37 etc.` so are they stored that way in SQL as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As binary. But since it's hard to display binary as text, you get a hexadecimal representation.

Comment: and when I'm making a SELECT statement and comparing, is MSSQL going to give me the binary or the hexadecimal representation basically?

Comment: The latter. You can't reliably display binary as text